# Error says that 'ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have already looked into some questions like this but none of them were useful on my case. I'm receiving a obj that returns a list of cities with their names, habitants and states.
Here's my http service request:

```
cidadesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/cidades';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  listar(): Observable<Cidade[]>{
    return this.http.get<Cidade[]>(this.cidadesUrl);
  }
```

and here's the calling to the service:

```
  cidades!: Cidade[];

  constructor(private cidadeService:CidadeService) { }

  listar(){
    this.cidadeService.listar().subscribe(data => { this.cidades = data });
    console.log(this.cidades);
  }
```

and my html:

```html
<p-table [value]="tabela" [paginator]="true" [rows]="4" responsiveLayout="scroll">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Habitantes</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-cidade>
      <tr>
          <td>{{cidade.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.qtdHabitantes | number}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.estado}}</td>
          <td class="acoes">
            <button pButton icon="pi pi-pencil" pTooltip="Editar" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
            <button pButton class="p-button-danger" icon="pi pi-trash"  pTooltip="Excluir" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Tabela variable:

```
@Input() tabela: Cidade[] = [];
```

Cidade Class

```
export class Cidade {

  id!: number;
  nome!: string;
  qtdHabitantes!: number;
  estado!: string;

}
```

I don't know why but when the page loads, i get the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function
    at Table.get dataToRender [as dataToRender] (primeng-table.mjs:398)
    at Table_table_7_Template (primeng-table.mjs:1840)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9618)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9484)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10609)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9508)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9534)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655)
```

When I open the Network tab in console, the cities are there, but they dont show up in the table
[image: ![enter image description here]

I dont know what could be possibly generating this error. Hoping someone can help

Comment: can you print what's coming in tabela? maybe print it in ngOnChanges?

Comment: The `.slice` error points that data is not an array, but probably an object. As I said in your previous/other question, your service returns an object that has another object at its top-level (content) and only there you have an array. So if your `tabela` has a value of `data` from service, then you need to set it to `data.content`.

Comment: I implemented a `console.log(this.tabela)` on the method OnInit() and its coming undefined

Comment: Hi @MishaMashina, i have already tried implementing the data.content, but it displays the error `Property 'content' does not exist on type 'Cidade[]'.`

Comment: Yes, but since the other issue has been solved, you had no need to add the Cidade interface, but can you please add it here?

Comment: I dont have the Cidade Interface, only the class that i just added

Comment: Ok, so what happens if you change `tabela` (or `cidades`, if tabela is just cidades, but received from Input) type to `any`? And then try with tabela.content (or cidades.content) or set cidades to data.content. It's obvious that you *really* need the `content` from the subscription data, not the whole data object, and the Cidade[] interface is obviously not going to work with that structure.

Comment: don't do in ngoninit instead do it in ngonchanges, i mean the console.log

Comment: What should i use then, instead of using the interface Cidade[] @MishaMashina ?

Comment: @AakashGarg the console log shows an Object with a array that has all of the cities in the content

Answer (score 0):

Keep type of your input like below :-

```
@Input() tabela: {content: Cidade[]};
```

and template like :-

```
<p-table [value]="$any(tabela)?.content" [paginator]="true" [rows]="4" responsiveLayout="scroll">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Habitantes</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-cidade>
      <tr>
          <td>{{cidade.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.qtdHabitantes | number}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.estado}}</td>
          <td class="acoes">
            <button pButton icon="pi pi-pencil" pTooltip="Editar" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
            <button pButton class="p-button-danger" icon="pi pi-trash"  pTooltip="Excluir" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

notice the question mark i have put after tabela in template. everything else is same.

Comment: After adding the `@Input() tabela!: {content: Cidade[]};` and `tabela?.content` im getting the error `Type 'Cidade[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.`

Comment: also im getting this error in the localhost page: `Property 'content' is missing in type 'Cidade[]' but required in type '{ content: Cidade[]; }'.`

Comment: updated the template please check

Comment: now its only giving the error `Property 'content' is missing in type 'Cidade[]' but required in type '{ content: Cidade[]; }'.` , the other one its gone

Comment: unless you give me the object thats coming in tabela can't help you. or try the updated template.

Comment: @Igor, going with @Aakash's answer - what happens if you remove `Cidade` type from your service and replace it with `any`? Like: 
`listar(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.cidadesUrl);
  }`

Comment: Hi @AakashGarg thanks for your help, i've manage to solve the errors :)

Comment: Also thank @MishaMashina for your help as well, you helped me to indetify what was the error about

Comment: please mark it as answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error has to do with the list being `undefined`:

```
ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function
```

You would need to set initial state, maybe something like this:

```js
@Input() tabela!: Cidade[] = [];
```

The exclamation `!` tells TS to assume a value has been set and it is not `undefined` but this may not be a valid assumption at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inizialize tabela property like

```
@Input() tabela: Cidade[] = [];
```

Looks like the table is trying to access tabela but it is not the kind of data it's expecting

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

you have to do `data?.content.slice` because data has content which is an array and what you want to run slice on.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer, but when i try to add the `data?.content.slice` it shows the error `Property 'content' does not exist on type 'Cidade[]'.` Should i use any instead o Cidade[]?

Comment: so put everything you have defined inside Cidade implementation inside the content maybe. Because it is not finding it. Or for testing purposes givy it any type instead of Cidade.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the everyone who helped me, i manage to solve the errors

So basically what i did was:

my html:

```
<p-table [value]="tabela" [paginator]="true" [rows]="4" responsiveLayout="scroll">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Habitantes</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-cidade>
      <tr>
          <td>{{cidade.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.qtdHabitantes | number}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.estado}}</td>
          <td class="acoes">
            <button pButton icon="pi pi-pencil" pTooltip="Editar" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
            <button pButton class="p-button-danger" icon="pi pi-trash"  pTooltip="Excluir" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Service: (changed the Cidade to type any)

```
export class CidadeService {

  cidadesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/cidades';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  listar(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.cidadesUrl);
  }

  salvar(cidade:Cidade){
    return this.http.post<Cidade>(this.cidadesUrl, cidade);
  }

}
```

Tabela Component

```
export class TabelaCidadesComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() tabela: any[] = [];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(this.tabela){
      const contentKey: any = Object.keys(this.tabela)[0];
      this.tabela = this.tabela[contentKey];
      console.log(this.tabela);
    }
  }

}
```